# How to use a segmented control to change container views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I actually just posted, but I am re-asking to give a better concept.

I'm trying to use a segmented control change through multiple views inside a container view. I'm also not sure how to embed multiple views inside the container view. I saw a tutorial how to do it in Objective-C, but I am coding in Swift.

[image: Twitter]

This is a perfect example of what I'm looking for. There is a UITabBarController on the bottom, but there is a segmented control to alter between "Tweets" "Photos" and "Favorites." How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a collection view or table view or something below the segmented control. If that's the case, I've had good luck using the segmented control to switch data sources (and delegates, if necessary) for the collection. If you just have views, you can use the segmented control to show one and hide the others.

Do you have any code or more specific questions?

Comment: Well, yes, but I have that inside a container view because the views will change from a table view. I want to use the segmented controller alter the views inside the container view because each view will be completely different from the others, such as one view would be a table view, one would be a collection view, etc

Comment: So then you can do what I suggested next - when one of the segments is selected, set the appropriate `view1.hidden = false` and the others `view2.hidden = true` and `view3.hidden = true`.